# Ortho- Para- Hydrogen Names and Benzene

Tags: hydrogen

I read that the Hydrogen atoms with nuclear spin in same direction are called Ortho- Hydrogen whereas those in opposite nuclear spin are Para- Hydrogen. But is there any resemblance of such a nomenclature with Ortho- Meta- Para- of Benzene, cause for benzene, these denote the relative position of substituent. Or is it just named so?

Comment: Coincidental naming.

Comment: There are ortho- and paracompact spaces in math (and meta-, too). No relation. We people are lazy bunch, we use the same word over and over again until it looks like a dirty rag, and then some.

Comment: And there is also ortho and meta phosphoric acid as yet different usage, describing different hydration levels of element oxoacids.

Comment: [For "_ortho-_"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BD%80%CF%81%CE%B8%CF%8C%CF%82#Ancient_Greek); [for "_para-_"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%80%CE%B1%CF%81%CE%AC#Ancient_Greek); [for "_meta-_"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BC%CE%B5%CF%84%CE%B1-#Ancient_Greek).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no connection of ortho- para- organic nomenclature with the nuclear spin isomerism of hydrogen. However, that raises an interesting point, that which nuclear state should be called the ortho- vs. para- or what was the thought process among the early German discoverers?

[Subscription only access: Farkas, L. (1933). *Über Para- und Orthowasserstoff. In: Ergebnisse der Exakten Naturwissenschaften*, vol 12. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg. https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0111841]

"*Die antiparallele Kernspinorientierung entspricht einem, "Kernspinsingulett" Zustand mit dem statistischen Gewicht I, die parallele Kernspinorientierung dem , Kerntriplett"-Zustand mit dem statistischen Gewicht 3*."

Then a footnote reads on later pages:

"...*Im allgemeinen werden immer die Zustände mit dem größeren statistischen Gewicht als Orthozustände bezeichnet*."

which means that the antiparallel nuclear spin orientation corresponds to a nuclear singlet state with a statistical weight of 1, the parallel nuclear spin orientation corresponds to the nuclear triplet state with a statistical weight of 3. **In general, the states with larger statistical weight are designated as ortho- states in nuclear spin isomers.**

Perhaps this ortho- nomenclature is due to the other meaning of *ortho* which means,  ‘right, correct, proper’, so the *majority* (=higher statistical weight) of the hydrogen's nuclear isomer is in the correct form/proper form, hence this is ortho- nuclear spin isomer of hydrogen.

Comment: o-together, p-opposite there might be a connection.

Comment: @jimchmst, Are you suggesting that those hardcore physicists were inspired by organic nomenclature, that is most likely not the case :-) So far, I could not find any.